# Qt Quick output is displaying incorrectly after compile

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-quick

I designed a form in Qt Quick and compiled it for Android. When executed on simulated Android device the form appears completely different!

I aligned the components to each other but nothing changed! (All items are in a `Rectangle`)

**Is it a good idea to use Widgets instead of Qt-Quick?**

This is what I designed:

[image]

And this is what I've got:

[image]

This is the QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow1
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    x: -273
    y: 145
    width: 223
    height: 128
    color: "#ffffff"
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

    TextField {
        id: textField1
        y: 18
        text: qsTr("")
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 16
        placeholderText: qsTr("نام کاربری")
    }

    Label {
        id: label1
        y: 25
        text: qsTr("نام کاربری")
        anchors.left: textField1.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 19
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField2
        y: 57
        width: 127
        height: 20
        text: qsTr("")
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 16
        placeholderText: qsTr("کلمه عبور")
    }

    Label {
        id: label2
        y: 64
        text: qsTr("نام کاربری")
        anchors.left: textField2.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 19
    }

    Button {
        id: button1
        x: 74
        width: 75
        height: 23
        text: qsTr("ورود")
        anchors.top: textField2.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 20
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have too many hardcoded positions and sizes in there. The Android device will have a much higher resolution so things are off, compared to your desktop screen. Rely more on anchoring.

Comment: What do you mean? Do I need not to mention size and positions?

Comment: The code is generated with designer. Do I need to write them myself?

Comment: That, or fix the anchoring in the designer. (I never used it, from what I've seen it's not very useful and one is better off writing the QML by hand)

Comment: IMO the designer if useful to create simple forms, like this, or for setting up more complex form - which are refined by hand. That said, leave to Qt the sizing, just anchor the components or use layouts, like in this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-basiclayouts-example.html). Different Android devices have different visual appearance (and sizes). You cannot handle them by setting values directly.